10 groups of 3 people from 30 people
I study maths and I came up with this question from my reallife soccer event.
In how many ways can a group of 30 people split into 10 groups of 3 people, so that no two people are ever in the same group.
First Series:
(1,2,3)
(4,5,6)
...
(28,29,30)
Second Series:
(1,4,7)
(2,5,8)
...
It would not be possible to have a group with (1,2,3) in the first series and (1,2,4) in any other series for example.
So the question is how many different series are possible?
I have solved the first part. The total ways of selecting people/group combinations is:
$\binom {30}{3}\ . \binom {27}{3} .\binom {24}{3} ... .\binom {3}{3}$
and since the order of the groups doesn't matter we divide by 10!
But I am stuck on the second part. Can you help me with that?

unfortunately the answers dont help. my question is very similar to the given questions. but the given answers only show one round of selection. i want three rounds of selection, but in each round no two people can be in the same group of three. lets take (6 3): first round could be [1,2,3] [4,5,6]. second couldnt round be: [1,2,4][3,5,6]. because 1,2 and 5,6 have been together in the first round. in that case i can only have one unique set of groups of three

@TurquoiseTilt I agree with the OP (i.e. original poster) that the question that you linked to is not a duplicate.  The linked article would yield $~\displaystyle \frac{30!}{(3!)^{10} ~10!}~$ which the OP has already derived.  The OP has explicitly stated that if one partition involves (for example) $~{1,2,3},~$ that no other partition may include any subset that includes at least two of the elements from $~{1,2,3}.$

To the OP:  My personal reaction to this problem is that on the one hand, it is interesting and may be very difficult to analytically attack.  On the other hand, there is a possible note of ambiguity in the posted question.  Various strategies used to construct a series of satisfying partitions may generate different results as to the maximum number of partitions possible.  I infer from your posted question that you are interested in the strategy that maximizes the resulting number of partitions, and are then interested in what this maximum enumeration is.

To the OP: Keeping in mind that my knowledge of graph theory is approximately equal to that of a randomly chosen giraffe, I wonder if your posted question can be analytically attacked without graph theory.

This question seems related to Kirkman's schoolgirl problem (which I don't know much about).
